# How is link-to used with a nested route when resetNamespace is specified?

Tags: ember.js

Using the example route defined below how can a link be defined to /post/123/comments?

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
    this.route('comments', { resetNamespace: true }, function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

Since `resetNamespace: true` is set on comments, the route post.comments does not exist.  Otherwise the following would work.

```
{{#link-to "post.comments" "123"}}Link{{/link-to}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to link directly to `comments`:

```
{{#link-to "comments" "123"}}Link{{/link-to}}
```

It will transition to `/post/123/comments` after you click it. See [working demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/23a6ea574e582fa6532f).

Comment: It looks like I simplified the problem too much.  Your example works perfectly well for a single reference to the comments route.  The reason to use resetNamespace is to allow the same comments route handler to be reused.  See this [example](https://ember-twiddle.com/23a6ea574e582fa6532f?code=e362dd44e7014c9694bb&state=GDI9jGbTPhWHMBSx).  The issue is that ember throws an error: `More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: comments`.

Comment: Marking this one as answered as the answer is correct for the question as asked.  The question for how to link to a reused route is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723861/how-are-ember-links-to-reused-nested-routes-defined-using-link-to].