# How are ember links to reused nested routes defined using link-to?

Tags: ember.js

Using the example route defined below how can a link be defined to /post/123/comments?

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
    this.route('comments', { resetNamespace: true }, function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
  this.route('comments');
});
```

Since `resetNamespace: true` is set on comments, the route post.comments does not exist.  Otherwise the following would work.

```
{{#link-to "post.comments" "123"}}Link{{/link-to}}
```

When trying to link to news using the comment id, the error `More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: comments` occurs.

```
{{#link-to "comments" "123"}}Link{{/link-to}}
```

An example of the second case can be seen here: https://ember-twiddle.com/d9f3b5e692573c80e803

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you have two routes with the same name? Try giving them unique names.

Comment: The idea is to reuse the same route handlers and provide a way to access similar resources from multiple points in the application.  The route handling works well, the only thing that isn't working is creating a link to each part of the application.

Comment: You are not reusing routes, you are pretending that you are reusing them. If your users will end up in the route `comments` from one point or another, there is not need to have a `post.comments` route. Just redirect the links from `post` route to `comments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're resetting the namespace, you are effectively overriding one of the `comments` route with the other. You're doing something akin to

```
obj['comments'] = firstRoute;
obj['comments'] = secondRoute;
```

Route names need to be unique, which they would be if you didn't reset the namespace, as well as the path. If two routes have the `/foobar` path, then Ember won't know which one to transition to.

If what you want is to reuse parts from other routes, [there are ways to do that](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/rendering-a-template/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to locks for pointing me in the direction.  The specific issue is how to reuse as much of the route and template as possible for different paths.

router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
    this.route('comments', function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
  this.route('comments');
});
```

routes/post/comments.js:

```js
import Comments from '../comments';

export default Comments.extend({
  renderTemplate() {
    this.render('comments');
  }
});
```

This will extend the existing comments route to reuse the model and actions defined in the base route.  The renderTemplate is still necessary to load the comments template instead of the post.comments template.